# Can't change tabs in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a `GridView` and `Mouse_DoubleClick` event that handles to create new `UserControl` that contains a`TabControl` in it.

**.xaml**

```
   <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GrdReports" MouseDoubleClick="GrdReports_OnMouseDoubleClick" CanUserInsertRows="True" Style="{DynamicResource RadGridViewNormal}">
      <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{Binding [Id], Source={StaticResource localization}}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{Binding [OrderNumber], Source={StaticResource localization}}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding OrderNumber}"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
       </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

**.cs**

```
    private void GrdReports_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GrdReports.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var currentReport = (Report)GrdReports.SelectedItem;
            var reportControl = new ReportControl { Report = currentReport };
            WeakEventManager<ReportControl, DialogClosedEventArgs>.AddHandler(reportControl, "DialogClosed", ReportControl_Closed);
            Dp.Show(reportControl);
        }
    }
```

And then the `UserControl` below created.

**.xaml**

```
 <telerik:RadTabControl x:Name="TabMainReport" Style="{DynamicResource RadTabControlWithTopBorderStyleCloseable}" Margin="-1 0 0 0">
        <telerik:RadTabItem x:Name="TabAddReport" Header="{Binding [ReportInformations], Source={StaticResource localization}}">
            <HeaderedContentControl Style="{DynamicResource HeaderedContentControlNormal}" Header="{Binding [AddReport], Source={StaticResource localization}}" Margin="10" Padding="0">

                             ...
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </telerik:RadTabItem>
        <telerik:RadTabItem x:Name="TabAddInspector" Header="{Binding [InspectorInformations], Source={StaticResource localization}}">
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="DckAddInspector" Margin="10">
                <HeaderedContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{DynamicResource HeaderedContentControlNormal}" Header="{Binding [AddInspector], Source={StaticResource localization}}" Margin="10" Padding="0">

                             ...
                </HeaderedContentControl>
    </telerik:RadTabControl>
```

I tried `SelectionChanged` event but nothing changed. The tabs are unresponsive. Literally nothing happens when I click those `TabItems`. Can you see why?